# `requests` installed, but error occurs while installing

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-requests

System info:

```
Windows 11 Home Edition 21H2 (22000.2416)
Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 28 2023, 22:05:19) [GCC 11.3.0] on cygwin
pip 23.2.1
requests 2.31.0
```

The terminal output:

```
PS> pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\bians\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\bians\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\bians\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\bians\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\bians\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2023.7.22)
PS> python
Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 28 2023, 22:05:19) [GCC 11.3.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
>>>
```

- There is no need to `pip install` as seen.
- I don't think there are problems with multiple versions of Python as the version shown at `pip` is the same with Python.
- I don't use PyCharm.
- Restarting or reinstalling `requests` does not work.
- The most confusing thing is that `requests` worked yesterday but error occurs today. I searched on the net with no luck.

Comment: It's the first time to use StackOverFlow for me, but I don't know how to revise the title.

Comment: _the version shown at pip is the same with Python_ This does not necessarily matter; you could have two separate installations of Python 3.11.  Show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: As a rule, never run `pip` but instead run `python -m pip` so you *know* it's the same installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be installing packages to different environment than currently using to run script.

- If you are using VS Code, (on windows) press ctl + shft + P and choose "Python : Select Interpreter". Make sure you are using the correct 3.11.5 version in your current project environment (or apply it globally, however not best practice).
- @John Gordon's point is similar I believe, in checking that the sys.path of your current project env. refers to the same installation path of requests package in your output window: "c:\users\bians\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages"

Answer (score 0):

**HOW I SOLVED THE PROBLEM**

First of all thanks to all the guys who helped me. Due to your suggestions, here is how I found where the problem is:

When the problem happens, first find out if the Python that `pip` stands for is the SAME Python as the Python we use. `I don't think there are problems with multiple versions of Python as the version shown at pip is the same with Python.` For Windows native toolchain it's actually true, but when I tried to install `gdb` yesterday "a Python" was installed to MSYS with `gdb` as a dependence. That's to say, the Python I used today is NOT the same as the Python yesterday. To confirm this, run what @John Jordon says.